# SQLException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SCHOOL.STUDENT_STAGE_FK) violated - child record found

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Here i have a problem in my code when i want to delete a record:(student) from database and i know there is a related key
but i cannot solve this problem i tried deleting student that on the stage  and this is the code:

```
public int deleteStudentStage(int stdId) //delete student by stId
{
    DatabaseConnection dbconn = new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection conn = dbconn.getConn();
    PreparedStatement pStm = null;
    int rows = 0;
    try
    {
        //String sql = "DELETE FROM STUDENT_STAGE WHERE STUDENT_ID = ? AND STAGE_ID = ?";

        String sql = "DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE ID = ? ";

        pStm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        //fill SQL parameters from student: //
        pStm.setInt(1, stdId);

        // excute //
        rows = pStm.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
     finally
    {
        try {
            conn.commit();
            pStm.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());;
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
```

[here the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbMrS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you give more information about it?, normally that happens when you have a foregin key, in this case of the table STUDENT, you need to delete all rows in the other table first before delete STUDENT, you also can solve it, adding a delete on cascade, when you create the foregin key

you need then do the following:

```
DELETE FROM STUDENT_STAGE WHERE STUDENT_ID=? 
DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE ID = ?
```

also you can update the foregin key in the table  for cascade delete:

```
ALTER TABLE STUDENT_STAGE DROP FOREIGN KEY STUDENT_STAGE_FK; 
ALTER TABLE STUDENT_STAGE ADD CONSTRAINT STUDENT_STAGE_FK FOREIGN KEY STUDENT_ID REFERENCES STUDENT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Whith the update of the foregin key, deleting a studen, you also delete all the information of this student in the table STUDENT_STAGE

Comment: yes i know this happens but i have but i want to delete a specific student on a specific stage instead of delete on cascade ,, do you understand me?

Comment: i think that yes, i understoo you @mohamedn , but you need to delete the info in the table stage, for this student, before delete the student, or you can update the foregin key named `SCHOOL.STUDENT_STAGE_FK`for delete in cascade

Comment: this the point , how can i delete the info in table stage for specific student however, the specific stage has more one student so how can i fix this problem.
can you write a code sql command for this as an  example

Comment: yes, i can write it, but can you share the schema of those tables?

Comment: of course , am added a link above that contain the schema image @MarcoPens

Answer (score 0):

First you need to delete elements from child table, you even have almost right query for this.

```
DELETE FROM STUDENT_STAGE WHERE STUDENT_ID=?
```

And after this delete student with current query.

Answer (score -1):

You must pass Value in where clause which student id you need to delete.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE ID = '"+stdId+"' ";
```